# What RuntimeException can Spring CrudRepository throw?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have this Spring Data `CrudRepository` which handles the CRUD operations on a DB.

```
@Repository
public interface IUserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

}
```

`User` is the Entity of a User table of my DB. `CrudRepository` adds namely the following operations to the repository:

- `delete(String ID)`
- `findOne(String ID)`
- `save(User user)`

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html), the delete and find operations throw `IllegalArgumentException` in case the given id is null while the save operation doesn't throw any exception.

The problem is that the javadoc of the CrudRepository makes no mention about the other exceptions thrown by these operations. For example it doesn't tell that the `delete(String ID)` operation throws a `EmptyResultDataAccessException` in case the provided ID is nonexistent in the DB.

In the javadoc of the `save(User user)` operation it's not clear which exceptions are thrown in case you insert a new User which breaks one data integrity constraint (on unique fields and foreign keys). Moreover it doesn't warn you whether you are writing a new or existent User: it just creates a new User or overwrites if existent (so it's a Insert + Update operation).

In a enterprise application I should be able to catch every throwable exception an operation can throw and I should read about that in the operation's javadoc.

Do you know any clear documentation about `CrudRepository` exceptions?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Spring has built-in exception translation mechanism, so that all exceptions thrown by the JPA persistence providers are converted into Spring's [DataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html) - for all beans annotated with @Repository (or configured).

There are four main groups -

- [NonTransientDataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/NonTransientDataAccessException.html) - these are the exceptions where a retry of the same operation would fail unless the cause of the Exception is corrected. So if you pass non existing id for example, it will fail unless the id exists in the database.
- [RecoverableDataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/RecoverableDataAccessException.html) - these are the "opposite" of the previous one - exceptions which are recoverable - after some recovery steps. More details in the API docs
- [ScriptException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptException.html) - SQL related exceptions, when trying to process not well-formed script for example.
- [TransientDataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/TransientDataAccessException.html) - these are the exception when recovery is possible without any explicit step, e.g. when there is a timeout to the database, you are retrying after few seconds.

That said, the ideal place to find documentation about all exceptions - is in the API itself - just go through the hierarchy of [DataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html).

Comment: Appreciate you supplying links to all the exceptions and explaining in detail what they mean.

Comment: @vtor what do you mean by "built-in exception translation mechanism". I am curious why spring documentation doesn't explicitly says that some methods throw this DataAccessException, for example save method of CrudRepository class.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you learn this?  Where could I have learned this, without resorting to consulting Stack Overflow?

Comment: One question about this exceptions and transactional annotation, if I catch any of this exceptions will the rollback still happen? Because maybe I need to do something like notify a service of this failure but I still want the rollback to be triggered by the Transactional annotation (if any of this exception happens, but at the end I think it is the DataAccessException)

Answer (score 1):

I capture the parent exception DataAccessException.

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
```

[image]

Comment: Im having massive issues with this. Been trying all day to figure this out. I wanted to throw Http status exception when this happens

Comment: Im using Exception type in catch block, still error with unique constraint not hitting the catch block.. what would be the cause?

Comment: @Veswanth did you manage to catch it?

Comment: Also if you do this (catch the DataAccessException) will the rollback still be triggered? For example this Jpa methods all have the Transactional annotation which makes sure that if anything goes wrong it rollbacks the transaction, it sill happens if you catch this exception?