# Why am i getting a org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException instead of a DataIntegrityException for hibernate spring boot?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'am using PostgreSQL 9.5 and here is my temperory entiy structure is :

i can not share the actual code .

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
 class MyEnity{

@Id
Long id;

@Column(name="another_entity")
AnotherEntity anotherEntity;

// other attributes with their getters and setters
}
```

and my save function is

```
public class saveEntitys{

@Transactional
public MyEntity saveEntity(MyEntity entity){

  MyEntity result;
  result = myrepository.saveAndFlush(entity); // myrespository is extending JpaRepository
  saveAnotherEnity(entity.getAnotherEntity());
  return result

}

void saveAnotherEnity(AnotherEntity ae)
{
try{
   myrepository.saveAndFlush(ae);
}catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
// do something
}

}
```

but the code is not throwing `DataIntegrityViolationException` as expected but instead throwing  `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException`.

curiously , it does throw `DataIntegrityViolationException` when i use `save()` function.

so why does it behave diffently for different function.

note : my question is why it behaves diffrently for different funtion and not the different type of exception the JPA stores

this is the exception i get :

```
2019-11-20 | 20:17:09.117 | http-nio-9797-exec-4 | ERROR | o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] | Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/provisioningService] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_lxbumlo3w7j6oen1megeiji5p"
  Detail: Key (customer_entiy_name)=(name_20102) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3174) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3688) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1453) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1439) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:533) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:504) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$Repos
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring CrudRepository exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325413/spring-crudrepository-exceptions)

Comment: the question is completly different